# How to convert a csv file into to a list of list that is readable as text? python

Tags: python, csv

I have a cvs file with one column and 300,000 individual text lines, which I would like to convert into a list of list. So that I get a list of 300,000 lists, with every sentence readable as a string.

When I open the csv as a DataFrame and convert it into a series, every sentence is split into letter.

```
sentence = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", encoding='utf-8') 
sentence = pd.Series([sentence])
sentence = sentence.tolist()

This gives:

[[('W', 'h', 'a', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'e', 'p'
```

Instead, what I would like is for example when I would print(sentence), it would show:

```
[['What is the step by step approach for building a house?'],['The
first step is securing an adequate plot.'] etc....]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Look up the `join()` method.

Comment: Specifically, just do `newlist = ["".join(val) for val in sentence]`

Comment: What does the raw file look like? I am not seeing why you are using csv to read a list of text lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just skip `read_csv` and read the file as just a file. See: [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

In your case, you can throw out the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just one column, why not just open it as a regular text file?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([line for line in open('myfile.csv', 'r')])
```